# change from xboxdrv to xpad driver

Tags: 12.04, drivers, steam, xbox-360

My computer (Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity) recognizes and works with my wired xbox360 controller with jstest-gtk and my Steam games recognize that the controller is there but buttons and joysticks input do nothing. I installed the xboxdrv from following the isntructions from http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/06/ubuntu-xbox-controller-support-xboxdrv-driver and nothing happens. Performing

sudo rmmod xpad

and now I cannot even recognize the xbox360 controller at all. I don't know how drivers work with Ubuntu but I would like to at least re-enable the xpad driver as the default primary driver and disable the xboxdrv driver. Help.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of posterity, restarting your computer should fix this, unless you use `modprobe` to block `xpad`. If so, you can just use `modprobe` to unblock it. `xpad` is a **kernel-space** driver, whereas xboxdrv is a **userland** driver; xboxdrv is run by the user (even if it's done automatically in the background), but  xpad is "baked-in" to the linux kernel, so you can't really have replace it unless you've compiled your own kernel.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching on this issue for Ubuntu 20.04 I found that installing `xboxdrv` would blacklist the `xpad` driver so, although it was still there, it wouldn't be used. The solution was to remove the blacklist entry.

`sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/xboxdrv.conf`